# How to add molecules to a specific location in periodic box using gromacs?

Tags: molecular-modeling, gromacs

In gromacs using the commands, [command_1](https://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/current/onlinehelp/gmx-insert-molecules.html)

```
gmx insert-molecules -f run03.pdb -ci CL.pdb -o out.pdb -nmol 119
```

will distribute CL ions in the system randomly, but how to specify a specific location to put the ions or molecules. For example if my periodic box is $\pu{5*5*10 nm^3}$ I want to put the ions to the location of $\pu{x < 5 nm, y < 5 nm }$ but $\pu{ z > 8 nm}$ (of course randomly but specific) in another words top part of the box I have also tried, [command 2](https://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/current/onlinehelp/gmx-genion.html)

```
gmx genion -s ions.tpr -o out.pdb -p system.top -pname NA -nname CL -neutral
```

But this command only replaces the SOL molecules (water) or some another residue in system.

Can someone help me, many thanks may be some other software can edit the pdb file but adding lot of ions one by one is quite annoying.

Comment: This can be done by a software called "Packmol" . Did you try that?

Comment: Thanks I will check it out

Comment: I think you can do this using gmx insert-molecules using the `ip` and `dr` functionality. I have not used it, but the documentation makes it seem like this is what these options exist for. See https://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/current/onlinehelp/gmx-insert-molecules.html.

Even if it works, I would probably stick with `packmol`

Comment: @B.Kelly ```-ip``` and ```-dr``` function worked thanks

Comment: @NightShade I added it as an answer so there can be a sense of finality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GROMACS` should be able to do this using the `-ip` `-dr` options associated with the tool `insert-molecules`.

I have not used this myself, but the [GROMACS insert-molecules](https://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/current/onlinehelp/gmx-insert-molecules.html) documentation seems to indicate that these will do what you want. (now that you have tried them and they do work... well, now we know.)

As was also mentioned in the comments by @Vasista, the venerable [Packmol](http://leandro.iqm.unicamp.br/m3g/packmol/home.shtml) can  do this too.